# How do I join two models together without messing up the texture?

Tags: mesh, texturing

I have a model of a human body and a human head, and both models use the same texture file. When I go to join them together into one form, however, the head's texture jumps to all bundled in the lower left corner,messing it up. how can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you're dealing with in your question? Is your model UV unwrapped?

Comment: http://imgur.com/PH7mi44
The model is uv unwrapped and both models are textured correctly before joining.

Comment: Ctrl + J should join meshes without change their UV Mapping

Comment: @parameciostudio Tried this, it doesn't work. UV mapping is still reset.

Comment: @sycon Can you provide the blend file?

Comment: @parameciostudio I'm not sure how to do this...

Comment: @sycon you can attach the blend file on mega.co.nz and give us the download link with the key attached. I can confirm that CTRL + J should not move your UV Mapping at all. That's how I do it. My guess is that you probably have some sort of parents or meshes with different scale apply. Try ALT + A and select "Apply scale" then Join the mesh and see if it works.

Comment: @parameciostudio http://www.mediafire.com/download/bnccom4y2tb3ebt/dude.blend here's the file through mediafire

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are using two UV Maps with different names.

When you join the meshes, the UV Maps will be mantained:

[image]

[image]

If you want to merge the UV Maps, just assign them the same name before merging.

[image]